# how to use ldap_sasl_bind_s() with SSL, DN, password (no client cert)

Tags: ssl, ldap, sasl

I have ldap_sasl_bind_s() working fine with SSL and client cert (without DN and password) from 'C' windows program.
When I call ldap_sasl_bind_s() using SSL, DN and password (no client cert) it throws null pointer exception. Should this work or should I be using another api call?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the Sun LDAP SDK doc. Even if the client is not using client cert auth, it still needs to pass the cert7 database file on the previous ldapssl_client_init() call as the client verifies the server cert was signed by the cacert defined in the cert7 db.